# How to remove erronous tabs/new line from .vcf file?

Tags: python, pandas, file, vcf-vcard

I am working with a vcf file. I try to extract information from this file, but the file has errors in the format.

In this file there is a column that contains long character strings. The error is, that a number of tabs and a new line character are erronously placed within some rows of this column. So when I try to read in this tab delimited file, all columns are messed up.

I have an idea how to solve this, but don't know how to execute it in code. The string is DNA, so always has ATCG. Basically, if one could look for a number of tabs and a newline within characters ATCG and remove them, then the file is fixed:

ACTGCTGA\t\t\t\t\nCTGATCGA would become:
ACTGCTGACTGATCGA

So one would need to look into this file, look for [ACTG] followed by tabs or newlines, followed by more [ACTG], and then replace this with nothing. Any idea how to do this?

```
with open(file.vcf, 'r') as f:
    lines = [l for l in f if not l.startswith('##')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way with regex:

First read the file in:

```
import re

with open('file.vcf', 'r') as file:
    dnafile = file.read()
```

Then write a new file with the changes:

```
with open('fileNew.vcf', 'w') as file:
    file.write(re.sub("(?<=[ACTG]{2})((\\t)*(\\n)*)(?=[ACTG]{2})", "", dnafile))
```